# How to insert first, second, third, fourth, into a enumerate list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm working on a very simple document

I just want something simple. I want to create a list with ordinal numbers, but in letter, like: first, second, third, fourth but in spanish.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10):

It can easily be done with the `fmtcount` package, which has commands to convert counters to text, and `enumitem`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{fmtcount} 
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\Ordinalstring{enumi} step:, align=left, font=\color{Crimson}\bfseries]
  \item Details of the first step. 
    \item Details of the second step. 
    \item Of the third step. 
  \item Of the fourth step. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: This is just what I wanted, thanks!. But now I want to know if is possible to make it spanish and write it all in uppercase and feminine, like: PRIMERA, SEGUNDA, TERCERA

Comment: @Neuxis: Yes, fmtcount has multilingual support, see §4 of the documentation. You have to add `\FCloadlangspanish}` in your preamble, and further add a last optional argument to `\Ordinalstring`, which is the gender to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I had the **exact same needs** as Neuxis, and the answer by Bernard using both `fmtcount` and `enumitem` packages helped a lot, but I had to do some extra research, because getting the ordinal string to come out in femenine Spanish failed to work perhaps due to a **clash between the two packages**.  Here's my workaround (far from perfect, but it kind of works):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{kpfonts} %font with Bold and Italicized Small Caps
 \renewcommand\shapedefault{sc} % to get the entire document to print in Small Caps

 \usepackage{fmtcount} 
 \FCloadlang{spanish}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

 \begin{document}
 
 \begin{enumerate}[label=, left=0pt .. \parindent]
   \item \textbf{\Ordinalstring{enumi}[f]}. Detalles de la primera cláusula. 
   \item \textbf{\Ordinalstring{enumi}[f]}. Detalles de la segunda cláusula.
   \item  \textbf{\Ordinalstring{enumi}[f]}. Detalles de la tercera cláusula.
   \item  \textbf{\Ordinalstring{enumi}[f]}. Detalles de la cuarta cláusula.
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}​
```

[image: The resulting PDF]

If a more elegant solution exists, please contribute. Or should I post this as a question?

Comment: I think this works as an answer.  It's not clear to me what you tried, so I'm not sure why it didn't work.  But `label=\protect\Ordinalstring{enumi}[f].` wouldn't work because the `]` makes LaTeX think you're done with the options to the environment.  But it looks like `label={\protect\Ordinalstring{enumi}[f].}` works, if I'm understanding what you're aiming for.